# Browser "hangs" on edit txt action

Tags: list, browsers

I know that you cannot open txt file into Notepad from SharePoint for edit, instead of this  you should see the message "A Microsoft SharePoint Foundation compatible application could not be found to edit the document". My issue is when I tries to perform this action my browser "hangs" for a minute or two, after this I see the message above. What can cause this issue?

Comment: Is there any custom JavaScripts that fails or runs a longer time? It seems that happens to your site.

Comment: @Sascha, I don't see any error in firebug

Comment: My workaround was to check out into a local drafts folder and edit then checkin.